# Crop and extract polygon(not rectangle or square) out of an image using its 4 coordinates in flutter using dart

Tags: flutter, dart, crop

I am working on a **image Cropper**,

where I want to crop a random `4 sided polygon` which is not a square or rectangle.

In `dart` in `image` package we have `copyCrop` and `copyCropCircle` functions.

Using these functions we can crop a `rectangle` and `circle` out of an image.

There is nothing in dart if we want to crop the image using the 4 coordinates inside that image.

There is a `RepaintBoundary` widget in flutter using which we can extract the widget out.

I tried this, but his method degrades the quality of image.

[image]

Any idea ? How I can do this ?

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried it using `CustomPainter`?

Comment: I have achieved the above image feature of clipping images in any shape, I just want to crop it out(extract the cropped image).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [dynamic_image_crop](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_image_crop) package?
I'm currently working on the same matter, extending the package and overriding some parts of it to clip and crop images using custom shapes that are calculated automatically by an ai model.

I will share with you if this actually worked

Comment: That will be great, Thanks for your help

Comment: I have not used it, but will use it and see its functioning.

Comment: I used it but it is also giving the fixed shapes like rectangle ,circles etc